# How to create nested DIVs with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, nested, creation

i have this jquery script:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    $('<div class="drag" style="left:20px;"/>')
        .text( num++ )
        .appendTo( document.body )
        .css({ 
            top: $( window ).height() - 500 , 
            left:$( window ).width() - 500
        });
});
```

this will create: `<div class="drag" style="left:20px;"/></div>`

what i am interested in creating is this:

```
<div class="drag" style="left:20px;"/>
    <div class="handle SE">
    </div>
</div>
```

if i do this:

```
...
$('<div class="drag" style="left:20px;"/><div class="handle SE">')
.text( num++ )
...
```

jquery will create 2 separate di'vs and not nested.

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.wrap()`:

```
$('<div class="handle SE">')
  .text(num++)
  .appendTo(document.body)
  .wrap('<div class="drag" style="left:20px;"/>);
```

Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/r4Dz6/

In this particular example it's neccesary to call `.appendTo(document.body)` *before* the wrap is done because `.wrap()` returns the original element.  Calling `.appendTo` last would result in the newly wrapped parent element getting removed from the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var outer = $('<div class="drag">').text('foo');
var inner = $('<div class="handle SE">').text('bar');

$(outer).append(inner);
$(outer).appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('<div class="drag"><div class="handle"></div></div>')`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VaKAw/

**Edit:** actualy you've put `/` at the end of first `div`:

`$('<div class="drag" style="left:20px;"/><div class="handle SE">')`,

which made them not nested, without it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/nbT8m/